# How to slant \trianglelefteq?

Tags: symbols

I wish to use this symbol in latex.

[image]

I tried looking but the closest thing I could find is `\trianglelefteq` but of course, the line isn't slanted. How do I slant the line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For instance, `stmaryrd` has such a symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
slanted: & $A\trianglelefteqslant B$ \\
normal: & $A\trianglelefteq B$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general you can look in the comprehensive list of symbols (`texdoc comprehensive`) and often it is advantageous to [only import one character from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388).

Answer (score 4):

The `mathabx` package provides `\trianglelefteq`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$N \trianglelefteq G$
\end{document}
```

[image]